# custom tableview cells passing an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom tableview class and I would like to pass two properties when an image is clicked:

in my "MJCustomTableViewCell.h"

```
@property NSString *username;
@property UIImage *selectedImage;
```

I would like to pass the above properties. I currently have this in my code, but it does not work, it only shows a blank view controller.

in my MJCustomTableViewCell.m

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *vc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];

    ImageHelper *imageHelper = [self.imageDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageHelper.standardPhotoURL];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    vc.selectedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    vc.username = imageHelper.username;


}
```

it pushes it to an empty view controller.. but it shows a blank page.. I also have this in my MJCustomTableViewCell.m file

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionViewCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ImageHelper *imageHelper = [self.imageDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageHelper.standardPhotoURL];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.selectedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    self.username = imageHelper.username;
    cell.imageView.image = self.selectedImage;

    return cell;
}
```

I feel like my code is repetitive. Any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your detail view controller is set up to display the data that you are passing it? For example, have you added an imageView as a subview to the detailViewController's view that will hold the selectedImage, which you set as the selectedImage property on the vc?

In regards to why tapping the image might push to an empty view controller, since you do not call pushViewController:animated in the collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath delegate method, I think you might want to check your table view delegate. It is possible that you are pushing to an empty view controller in your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: yes it is set up to display the data. because i see the label that is supposed to show my username... in my custom tableview cell, in the method didSelectItemAtIndexPath, I am trying to get a pointer of the DetailsViewController by using DetailsViewController *vc = [UIStoryboard instantiateWithIdentifier...] but UIStoryboard does not show up and has an a error. could you please tell me why?

Comment: instantiateWithIdentifier is an instance method, not a class method. You would have to first get a reference to your storyboard with UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"<yourStoryboardName>" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]. Then you can call the instantiateWithIdentifier method on mainStoryboard.